find the bit position(s) which are exactly set twice over multiple bit fields
I've 9 bit fields every bit field has 9 nine bits, the 9 LSBs of an int.
I want to find the bit position(s) which are exactly set twice over all bit fields.
e.g:
    0.1111.1111
    0.0000.1101
    0.0001.1101
    0.0001.1101
    0.0010.1101
    0.0010.1101
    0.0100.1101
    0.0100.1101
    0.0000.0010

In this example its bit position 1 because at this position the 1 is exactly set two times.
The first time in the first bit field, the second time in the last bit field.
Currently I do a "positional population count" on ints.
for every possible bit field, there are 512, I have a corresponding long bit mask,
which is used to count the frequency of set bit positions.
0.0100.1101 -> 0000.0000.0001.0000.0000.0001.0001.0000.0001
I sum up the 9 long bit masks of the 9 bit fields.
So the first 4 LSBs of the sum represent the frequency bit 0 is set.
The second 4 bits represent the frequency bit 1 is set.
And so on, so I can scan for a frequency of 2.
This works, but its not as fast as I hoped.
Is there a faster algorithm which I can implement in Java?
I don't need to know all bit positions with a frequency of 2, just one bit position is fine.

Compared to a full pos-popcount, there is a shortcut.
You can find out two things:

which bits are set at least twice
which bits are set at least 3 times

Then you can find the bits that are set exactly twice as the intersection of the bits that are set at least twice with the bits that are not set at least 3 times.
int set_a1 = 0;
int set_a2 = 0;
int set_a3 = 0;
for (int i : values) {
    set_a3 |= set_a2 & i;
    set_a2 |= set_a1 & i;
    set_a1 |= i;
}
int set_twice = set_a2 & ~set_a3;

Then you can use Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros to get the position of the first (starting from the lsb) bit that was set twice.

That's an elegant solution, it doesn't need the precomputed long masks and its nearly 10% faster on my machine.
Also its the same idea, I used for finding the positions which are exactly set once: allBits - twiceOrMoreBits, but I wasn't able to extend it to the twice set bits case. So this also fits very well from this perspective.

@coder for the precomputed masks by the way, you may also use Long.expand in sufficiently new versions of Java. That may not be better than getting the expanded mask from an array, but there's a chance. Some processors have a native instruction for that expand operation.

interesting method, needed a while to understand what it does, eventually find the correct mask 0b0001_0001_..._0001L, and indeed
its seems a tiny bit faster than the lookup.

The values of the bits of the variable b are summed in the sum variable, but the carry after addition isn't added to the highest bit, but summed in the sumCarry variable.
In the same way, we can further summarize the carries in another variables, but it's enough for us to fix only the fact of the presence of the next carry in anyCarry variable.



number of bits
0
1
2
3
4 or more




sum
0
1
0
1
-


sumCarry
0
0
1
1
-


anyCarry
0
0
0
0
1


setTwice
0
0
1
0
0



var sum = 0;
var sumCarry = 0;
var anyCarry = 0;

for (var b : values) {
    var c = sum & b;
    sum ^= b;
    anyCarry |= sumCarry & c;
    sumCarry ^= c;
}

var setTwice = ~sum & sumCarry & ~anyCarry;


Also a nice way to do it, its a little bit slower (~20%, on my machine), compared to user555045 solution.

You could probably use a Map to maintain counts. Most of the following is just setup and visualization. It's just the getExclusivePairs that you need:
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BitSets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] bitSets = new int[9];
        final int MASK = 0b1_1111_1111;
        ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        IntStream.range(0, bitSets.length).forEach(ix -> bitSets[ix] = rand.nextInt() & MASK);
        System.out.println("  8 7654 3210");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        for (int j = 0; j < bitSets.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%d %s%n", j, StringUtils.toBinaryStringGrouped(bitSets[j]).substring(28));
        }

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> found = getExclusivePairs(bitSets); 
        found.entrySet().
            stream().forEach(e -> System.out.printf("Bit %d is set exactly twice in the following bitsets: %s%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }

    private static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> getExclusivePairs(int[] bitSets) {
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> counter = new HashMap<>();
        for(int ixBitset = 0;ixBitset < bitSets.length;ixBitset++) {  
            for(int ixBit = 0;ixBit < bitSets.length;ixBit++) {  
                boolean isSet = (bitSets[ixBitset] & (1 << ixBit)) > 0;
                if (isSet) {
                    counter.computeIfAbsent(ixBit, k -> new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(ixBitset);
                }
            }
        }
        return counter.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 2).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
    private static class StringUtils {
        public static String toBinaryStringGrouped(int n) {
            return StringUtils.grouped(StringUtils.toBinaryString(n));
        }

        private static String grouped(String s) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
            for (int i = sb.length() - 4; i >= 4; i -= 4) {
                sb.insert(i, '_');
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public static String toBinaryString(int n) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000000000000000000000000000000");
            for (int bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++) {
                if (((n >> bit) & 1) > 0) {
                    sb.setCharAt(31 - bit, '1');
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}


This also returns the two bit field indices which is nice, but from a performance perspective its a far way off from the other solutions.
